# Unable to retrieve ContentResult containing JSON string via ajax

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

My Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
Public ContentResult GetData()
{
  var jsonstring = "{{col: \"aaaaa\"},{col:\"bbbbbb\"},{col: \"cccccc\"}}";
  return Content(jsonstring,"application/json");
}
```

My Ajax Call:

```
$.get("GetData", function (data) {
       alert("back");
       $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            alert(item);
             //loop thru item and add to drop downs, make drop downs visible
        });
    });
```

The Controller method is getting called properly and does return, however It does not return back to the ajax call.  I would like to use JsonResult and return Json(....) however, I have a process that pre builds the Json string for me.  Do I need to deserialize it first?  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a poorly formed Json string - change outer brackets to [ ], and put double quotes around each key ie. "col":

This change will allow the content to be processed by the ajax call.